# How do I get NLTK to be in my pwd on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, jupyter, nltk

I'm a total beginner with this, so please excuse this question. I'm trying to learn Jupyter Notebook and NLTK, but don't know how to access NLTK. I have downloaded it, so I'm guessing it is somewhere in a different folder (pwd is C:\Users\leise\Applied Language Science). How do I find it, and how do I connect it to my present working directory, so I can start using it? I guess I messed up the folder structure at some point, but have no idea how to fix that, so I'm a bit lost right now :D ... The screenshot shows what I'm trying to do and the error message I'm getting.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean the `NLTK` package/library or the downloaded "stuff" e.g `stopwords`?

Comment: I'm not totally sure to be honest. This is the command I'm trying to run and below the error message I'm getting. Hope this helps. Thank you! 

with open('data\\carroll-alice.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as myFile:
    # the raw corpus as string
    rawText = myFile.read()

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16332/3283611648.py in <module>
  


FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data\\carroll-alice.txt'

Comment: Or maybe there is something wrong with the command, because the text seems to be there as I'm able to run ommands on it, for example print(alice.count("Alice"))) is working fine.

Comment: Also, when I try tokens = word_tokenize(alice) it generates  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object